# Creating Cloud Optimized GeoTiff through JavaScript

Tags: javascript, cloud-storage, gis

I want to create a desktop application using Electron and JavaScript that generates a Cloud Optimized GeoTiff (COG) from a single image (png, jpg, etc.).
The image's projection system and display range are already known, and a world file can be generated immediately if necessary.
If needed, re-projection to Web Mercator and splitting into WTMS tile format can also be completed in JavaScript.
While there might be several approaches to consider, I would prefer to avoid executing commands via the command line if possible.
If command line execution is unavoidable, the tool must work on both Windows and Mac, support both Intel and ARM architectures, and be executable portably without requiring prior installation.
WebAssembly is acceptable, but for manageability reasons, Pure JS is preferred if possible.
Given these conditions, I want to know the most efficient approach to generate a COG.

Comment: This is multi-posted on X: https://x.com/kochizufan/status/1764135398752862480?s=20